# Wiener measure integration

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, brownian-motion

Let $\mu_{x,y;t}$ be the Wiener measure generated by $\exp[t \Delta](x,y)$. 
I see in my book the following step:  for any $0\leq s \leq t$,

$$\int dx\int d\mu_{x,x;t}(\omega) \phi(x) = \int dx\int d\mu_{x,x;t}(\omega) \phi(\omega(0)) =  \int dx \int d\mu_{x,x;t}(\omega) \phi(\omega(s)) $$

The first '=' comes from $\omega(0) = x $. The second '=' comes from the fact that $\exp[t \Delta](x,y)$ forms a semi group.

However, I don't understand the second '='. How can I see this?

Comment: Which book? $ $

Comment: Geometry of the laplace operator, page 248 or 'The Number of Bound States of one-body Schroedinger Operators and the Weyl Problem' by E. Lieb

Comment: Which one is "your book"? Note that "Geometry of the laplace operator" does not suffice to characterize a book, by far.

Comment: Okay, I'm soory that I explained it in a bad way: It's from a paper called 'The Number of Bound States of one-body Schroedinger Operators and the Weyl Problem' by E. Lieb. This paper can be found in for example the book 'Geometry of the Laplace Operator': http://books.google.de/books/about/Geometry_of_the_Laplace_Operator.html?id=-XcTGjBuZS0C&redir_esc=y

Comment: Which is not available to read... One more try: in the basic $\mathbb R^d$ setting, each Wiener measure $W_x$ is a probability measure on the space $C([0,\infty),\mathbb R^d)$ of continuous functions $[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R^d$ hence each $W_{x,t}$ is a measure on $\mathbb R^d$, with density $w(x,\ ;t)$, say, hence each $w(x,y;t)$ is a **number**. In your post it seems that each $\mu_{x,y;t}$ should be a measure on $C([0,\infty),\mathbb R^d)$, can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is unclear, here is an interpretation. In the $\mathbb R^d$ case, let us assume that $\mu_{x,y;t}$ is the *Brownian bridge* probability measure on $\Omega=C([0,t],\mathbb R^d)$. In other words, for each $x$ in $\mathbb R^d$ and $t\gt0$,  $W_{x,t}$ is the Wiener measure on $\Omega$ of the Brownian motion $(B(s))_{0\leqslant s\leqslant t}$ of length $t$ starting from $B(0)=x$, and the family $(\mu_{x,y;t})_{y\in\mathbb R^d}$ is the decomposition of $W_{x,t}$ according to the value of $B(t)$, that is, $\mu_{x,y;t}(B(t)=y)=1$ for every $y$, and
$$
W_{x,t}(\,\cdot\,)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mu_{x,y;t}(\,\cdot\,)\,\mathrm d\nu_{x,t}(y),
$$
where $\nu_{x,t}$ is the distribution of $B(t)$ with respect to $W_{x,t}$. Consider the integral on the left of your double identity, namely,
$$
A_\varphi=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{x,x:t}(\omega)\varphi(x),
$$
then
$$
A_\varphi=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\varphi(x)\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{x,x:t}(\omega)=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\varphi(x),
$$
because $\mu_{x,x:t}$ is a probability measure. Likewise, the integral in the middle is
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{x,x:t}(\omega)\varphi(\omega(0))=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{x,x:t}(\omega)\varphi(x)=A_\varphi,
$$
because $\omega(0)=x$ almost surely for $\mu_{x,x;t}$. Finally, for every $s$ in $[0,t]$, the integral on the right is
$$
C_\varphi=\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{x,x:t}(\omega)\varphi(\omega(s)).
$$
Note that $\omega(s)$ under $\mu_{x,x:t}$ is distributed like $x+\omega(s)$ with respect to $\mu_{0,0;t}$ hence, using Fubini theorem,
$$
C_\varphi=\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{0,0:t}(\omega)\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dx\varphi(x+\omega(s))=\int_\Omega\mathrm d\mu_{0,0:t}(\omega)\int_{\mathbb R^d}\mathrm dz\varphi(z),
$$
by the change of variable $x=z-\omega(s)$, and finally,
$$
C_\varphi=A_\varphi.
$$
In the end, the crucial argument is the way the measures $\mu_{x,y;t}$ behave under the action of translations. No idea why the semi-group property should be involved here, or how the argument above would carry to the case of manifolds though.

Comment: Maybe because: $\int \text{d}x \int_\Omega \text d \mu_{x,x;t}(\omega) \phi(\omega(s)) = \int \text{d}x \int_\Omega \text d \mu_{0,0;t}(\tilde\omega) \phi(\tilde\omega(s) + x ) = \int \text{d}x \int_\Omega \text d \mu_{0,0;t}(\tilde\omega) \int \text{d}x \phi(\tilde\omega(s) + x ) = \int_\Omega \text d \mu_{0,0;t}(\tilde\omega) \int \text{d}x \phi(x)=\int \text{d}x \int_\Omega \text d \mu_{x,x;t}(\omega) \phi(x)$, first I made a shift $\omega(s)=\tilde\omega(s) + x$, then I evaluated the x-Integral and also shifted that.

Comment: Yes, I had thought about this argument in the $\mathbb R^d$ case but it crashes when one is on some manifold and Lieb is interested in Brownian motions on manifolds, ain't he?

Comment: The paper can also be found in 'Stability of Matter from atoms to stars'.

Comment: I'm only interested in $\mathbb R^d$ case. However, Lieb stated it indeed for (Riemann) manifolds. In 'Functional Integration and Quantum Physics' by Barry Simon on p. 91, Barry has an similar argument. He says that w.r. t. the measure $d\nu = dx d\mu_{x,x;t}$ the variables $\omega(s_1), \dots \omega(s_n)$ are identically distributed to $\omega(s_1 "+"a), \dots, \omega(s_n "+" a)$, where $s"+"a$ means addition mod $t$.